# How to get "onclick" value JS

Tags: javascript, onclick

I would like to know if is possible to get onclick value using Javascript.
I have this link:

```
<a onclick="window.open('WhatIWantToGet')"></a>
```

and I would like to get "WhatIWantToGet".

Comment: HOW do you want to get it? What action causes you to read it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the parameter to the function by getting the `onclick` attribute of the DOM node and parsing out the argument:

```
 var link = document.querySelector('a');
 alert(link.getAttribute('onclick').match(/'(.*)'/).shift());
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic regular expression to parse the onclick attribute. This assumes it will be single quotes around the string.

```js
var anchor = document.querySelector("a");
var re = /window\.open\('([^']+)/;
var txt = anchor.getAttribute("onclick").match(re);
console.log(txt ? txt[1] : "no match");
```

```html
<a onclick="window.open('WhatIWantToGet')"></a>
```